# Can a UIViewController that is presented as a popover be its own popoverPresentationController delegate?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, popover, uipresentationcontroller

In the project shown below there is an `InitialViewController` that has a single button labeled "Show Popover". When that button is tapped the app is supposed to present the second view controller (`PopoverViewController`) as a popover. The second view controller just has a label saying "Popover!".

[image: storyboard image]

This works fine if the `InitialViewController` takes care of instantiating `PopoverViewController`, retrieving the `popoverPresentationController` and then setting the popoverPresentationController's `delegate` to itself (to `InitialViewController`). You can see the result, below:

[image: functiong app when delegation occurs in InitialViewController]

For maximum reusability, however, it would be great if the `InitialViewController` did not need to know anything about how the presentation controller is delegated. I think it should be possible for the `PopoverViewController` to set itself as the popoverPresentationController's `delegate`. I've tried this in either the `viewDidLoad` or the `viewWillAppear` functions of the `PopoverViewController`. However, the `PopoverViewController` is presented modally in both cases, as shown below:

[image]

All the code is contained in just the `InitialViewController` and the `PopoverViewController`. The code used in the **failing** version of the `InitialViewController` is shown below:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - UIViewController subclass

class InitialViewController: UIViewController {

    struct Lets {
        static let storyboardName = "Main"
        static let popoverStoryboardID = "Popover View Controller"
    }

    @IBAction func showPopoverButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // instantiate & present the popover view controller
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: Lets.storyboardName,
                                      bundle: nil )
        let popoverViewController =
            storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Lets.popoverStoryboardID )
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        guard let popoverPresenter = popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController
            else {
                fatalError( "could not retrieve a pointer to the 'popoverPresentationController' property of popoverViewController")
        }
        present(popoverViewController,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil )

        // Retrieve and configure UIPopoverPresentationController
        // after presentation (per
        // https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller)

        popoverPresenter.permittedArrowDirections = .any
        let button = sender
        popoverPresenter.sourceView = button
        popoverPresenter.sourceRect = button.bounds

    }
}
```

The code in the **failing** `PopoverViewController` is shown below:

```
import UIKit


// MARK: - main UIViewController subclass

class PopoverViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: API
    var factorForMarginsAroundButton: CGFloat = 1.2

    // MARK: outlets and actions
    @IBOutlet weak var popoverLabel: UILabel!

    // MARK: lifecycle

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear( animated )

        // set the preferred size for popover presentations
        let labelSize =
            popoverLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting( UILayoutFittingCompressedSize )
        let labelWithMargins =
            CGSize(width: labelSize.width * factorForMarginsAroundButton,
                   height: labelSize.height * factorForMarginsAroundButton )
        preferredContentSize = labelWithMargins

        // set the delegate for the popoverPresentationController to self
        popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self

    }
}
// MARK: - UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
//       (inherits from protocol UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate)

extension PopoverViewController: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate
{
    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController,
                                   traitCollection: UITraitCollection)
        -> UIModalPresentationStyle{
            return .none
    }
}
```

Is it possible for a view controller that is being presented as a popover to be the delegate for its own `popoverPresentationController`?

I'm using Xcode 8.0, Swift 3.1 and the target is iOS 10.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly possible. You're dealing with a timing issue. You need to set the delegate before `viewWillAppear`. Unfortunately, there is no convenient view lifecycle function to insert the assignment into, so I did this instead.

In your `PopoverViewController` class, assign the delegate in an overriden getter. You can make the assignment conditional if you'd like. This creates a permanent relationship, so other code code never "override" the delegate by assigning it.

```
override var popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController? {
    get {
        let ppc = super.popoverPresentationController
        ppc?.delegate = self
        return ppc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Allen!  I just tried that and it worked perfectly.  I agree that it is a timing issue, but I had no clue that overriding a property would provide the correct timing. Can you give us an idea of how you figured that one out?

Comment: Honestly, a little trial and error. I found that the popoverPresentationController didn't exist yet after initialization and viewDidLoad was already to late. So I went the route of inserting myself between whatever part of the system consumes the popoverPresentationController

Comment: Hmm, I think I get it. ViewDidLoad won't happen unless the popoverPresentationController has been initialized and utilized, so a get of popoverPresentationController must come after the init and before ViewDidLoad.  Thank you again for your kind (and very quick) response.

Answer (score 0):

As @allenh has correctly observed, you need to set the delgate before `viewWillAppear`, and he has offered a clever solution by setting the delegate by overriding the `popoverPresentationController` getter.

You could also set the delegate to the popover itself in your `showPopover()` function between setting `modalPresentationStyle` and presenting the popover:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Lets.popoverStoryboardID )
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
vc.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = vc
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```